How to update marker location using react-native-maps
I have two markers displayed on my map. One static and the other representing a delivery driver. I can get the updated coordinates for the driver yet the location is not updated in the map. I assume that I don't need to do  full refresh in order to accomplish this:
class appMarker {
  constructor(title, location, description, icon) {
    this.title = title;
    this.location = location;
    this.description = description;
    this.icon = icon;
  }

  const customerMarker = new appMarker(
    "Customer Location",
    { latitude: 35.2, longitude: -119.3 },
    "GPS 88",
    "account-hard-hat"
  );
  const supplierMarker = new appMarker(
    "Supplier Location",
    { latitude: 35.4, longitude: -118.9 },
    "San Joaquin Bit",
    "truck-fast"
  );


I update the supplier marker every minute or so and this is how it is displayed:
<MapView
          provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={styles.statusView}
          onRegionChange={onRegionChange}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 35.411544488071556,
            latitudeDelta: 0.7141989335803416,
            longitude: -119.09790278932303,
            longitudeDelta: 0.9062909038644165,
          }}
          apiKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        >
          {/* Output Customer Marker */}
          <Marker
            coordinate={customerMarker.location}
            title={customerMarker.title}
            description={customerMarker.description}
          >
            <Icon
              style={{
                textAlign: "center",
                top: 5,
              }}
              name={customerMarker.icon}
              size={30}
              color="#E74c3c"
            />
          </Marker>
          {/* Output Supplier Marker */}
          <Marker
            coordinate={supplierMarker.location}
            title={supplierMarker.title}
            description={supplierMarker.description}
          >
            <Icon
              style={{
                textAlign: "center",
                top: 5,
              }}
              name={supplierMarker.icon}
              size={30}
              color="#E74c3c"
            />
          </Marker>

        </MapView>



I verify the changes to the supplierMarker coordinates yet the map is not updated.
...
    supplierMarker.changeLocation({
      latitude: location.coords.latitude,
      longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    });
    Alert.alert(
      "Current Supplier Location",
      JSON.stringify(supplierMarker.location)
    );
...
 

I expected the marker location to be updated once the coordinates were updated.
